# UX Perspective: Should my Single Sign On server be on the same domain?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, user-experience

I'm already developing a SSO server, providing access to my main app and also giving the ability to third party applications get user information through an oAuth2 implementation.

All these things (login, user management, sign up, access tokens) were developed in a totally separated project called "Credentials".

The thing is: In the User Experience perspective, should I use the main domain of my app for this section of the website such as https://app.com/auth?

I was planning to use it as a subdomain, like https://credentials.app.com/ it is easier as I won't have to create a path proxy (the main app is written in koajs and the Auth Server in express) but I'm afraid that some users won't insert their password there thinking that this url is fake. (Yeah, these stuff really happens).

What are your recommendations, did you also had this kind of dilemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above all you need to make sure that the application that collects the credentials presents a valid TLS certificate and that the domain reflects something that the user is familiar with to mitigate any confusion around phishing.

It may be convenient to use a specific path relative to the application that the user logged in to but only if the SSO system is used only for applications on that very same domain. If you are going to connect applications on subdomains or even other domains to the same SSO system, which is usually the goal of introducing an SSO system, then you may just as well use a separate (sub) domain.

Comment: Hello Hans! Thank you for your answer. After your answer, I'm thinking to use an external subdomain only for credentials. Do you suggest using some specific keyword like https://login.app.com/?

Comment: that sounds good, assuming `app.com` is a domain that users know and trust